# Getting a MIME type ('application/json') is not executable error. Any reason why?

Tags: html, json

Getting this error because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I'm creating a map on a webpage and have downloaded a JSON file with coordinates, however when trying to load this file in the head with a script tag the above error is thrown in Google Chrome.

```
<script src="js/londonM.json"></script>
```

Here is part of my JSON file:

```
var london_json = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",

   "features": [
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ward": "Chessington South", "gss_code_ward": 
  "E05000405", "gss_code_borough": "E09000021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a JavaScript file that contains a JSON array, not specifically a JSON file.

Rename the file to `londonM.js` and you'll be good to go.